# Echo Serial Strings with Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

EDIT 2: I got the solution. Anytime someone wants the code I'd be happy to provide. Peace.

Topic:
I'm trying an experiment of echoing strings that I receive in my arduino.
So this is the code so far:

```
byte byteRead = 0;
bool readable = LOW;

char fullString[50];
int index = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // State 1
  if (Serial.available()) {
    readable = HIGH; // flag to enter in the next state when there's nothing else to read
    byteRead = Serial.read();
    fullString[index] = (char)byteRead;
    index++;
  }
  // State 2
  if (readable == HIGH && !Serial.available()){
    fullString[index] = '\0'; // '\0' to terminate the string
    Serial.println(fullString);
    // resets variables
    index = 0;
    readable = LOW;
  }
  /** 
   *  Somehow a delay prevents characters of the string from having 
   *  a line printed between them.
   *  Anyways, when the string is too long, a line is printed between 
   *  the first and second characters
   */
   delay(5); 
}
```

Somehow this delay in the end prevents the characters of the string from having a line printed between them, like this:

H

e

l

l

o

Nonetheless, when the string is too long, a line is printed between the first and second characters.

Do you know a better way of doing this?

EDIT: Next time I'd appreciate answers from someone who actually KNOWS programming. Not just condescending idiots.

Comment: A better way of doing what? You haven't specified anything other than "echo serial strings".

Comment: «when the string is too long, a line is printed between the first and second characters» This method is not really reliable, and I haven't found any example so far.

Comment: Of course there is. You're using the method that prints a newline.

Comment: I know. I typed it myself. Shouldn't it print the newline only at the end of the string?

Comment: How do you detect that the string has ended? This is the question you have to answer....

Comment: It prints the newline at the end of the string that gets passed to it. But there is no requirement that the entire string be read at once.

Comment: @frarui87 fullString[index] = '\0'; // '\0' to terminate the string

Answer (score 0):

that's my String Echo

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 0xFF
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  buffer[0] = '\0';
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char incomingByte;
    size_t i = 0;
    do {
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      buffer[i++] = incomingByte;
    } while (incomingByte != '\0' && i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if(i > 0){
      delay(1000);   /// delay for the echo
      Serial.write(buffer, i);
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to echo the string read, so just echo the input.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int c = Serial.read();
  if (c >= 0) Serial.write(c);
}
```

Comment: But I want to echo a string, not a char.